# Write a csv file in a loop by rows then start a new output to a different column of the same file

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I want to output some results to a CSV file in a loop. The idea is to write it row by row and then output results to another column in a new loop. This seems a basic question but I cannot figure it out and only output my results row next row. My code is as below, the first line occupies one cell, and the rest lines occupy three cells in this case.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

```py
f2 = open("output.csv","w", newline='')
writer=csv.writer(f2)

for i in range(len(BeamNum)):
    writer.writerow([BeamNum[i]])
    writer.writerow(["time(s)", "Pos", "Max VM stress (Pa)"])
    for ii in range(NumPrimary.value):
        St7API.St7GetResultCaseTime(1,ii+1,cTime)
        St7API.St7GetBeamResultEndPos(1, St7API.rtBeamAllStress, St7API.stBeamGlobal,
                                      BeamNum[i], ii+1, NumCol, BeamRes)
        writer.writerow([cTime.value, 'End1', BeamRes[19]])
        writer.writerow([cTime.value, 'End2', BeamRes[41]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing CSV like that is a somewhat complicated thing.  Bytes are written to a file consequently, and adding another column requires *inserting* bytes, which is usually done by essentially saving the whole new file.

What you should do is to create tuples or lists representing result rows and write them one by one.  Since your code snippet can't be executed, let me demonstrate thusly:

```
import csv

data = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
data_sum = [sum(i) for i in data]  # [3, 7, 11]

with open('/tmp/sum.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['a', 'b', 'sum'])
    for ((a, b), s) in zip(data, data_sum):
        csv_writer.writerow([a, b, s])
```

Or replace `for` loop with `cvs.Writer.writerows()` call:

```
  csv_writer.writerows((a, b, s) for ((a, b), s) in zip(data, data_sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:    
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
 
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)

    # Start a new output to a different column of the same file
    # by writing an empty row to the CSV file
    writer.writerow([])
```

Comment: Adding empty row does *not* start a new column.